# framework for portal development

Tags: magento, drupal, odoo, portal, marketplace

I am currently evaluating frameworks to use as base for a custom portal development. So basically i am looking for a framework which covers the most basic functions, such as login, account management etc. for different user groups. Upon this base I would like to develop custom functionality for a special purpose online marketplace. So far I thought of two directions. either going with a shop system such as magento and start tweaking from there (however this seems quite inflexible) or using CMS such as drupal as a base and develop all further functionality as addon.
It also crossed my mind to use erp system such as odoo as a base since most business processees are already covered, but, there again, it might be pretty hard work to build a marketplace around odoo.

I'd be curious if i am missing some important directions or if there are any other frameworks out there, which can be used as a portal base. Anyone got experience with building portals based on a "standard" framework?

Answer (score 0):

**In Odoo There are several Number Portal Module Available in ODOO 8.0**

which are related with your sale,sale stock,crm project,gamification etc..

**The following modules are helpful for use with the portal Implementation for odoo 8.0**

```
1.portal
2.portal Gamification
3.portal claim
4.portal sale
5.portal sale stock
6.portal project
7.portal project issue
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it sound like Odoo 8 already answers your needs.

You want to use the Odoo [website](https://www.odoo.com/page/website-builder) features. It provides the basic functions you mention, and a framework to develop your own website or portal features.

Additionally, you also have ready to use features, such as [eCommerce](https://www.odoo.com/page/e-commerce) online shop,  a [blog](https://www.odoo.com/page/blog-engine) engine or user [forum](https://www.odoo.com/page/community-builder).